# What does this phrase signify 'Better a Live Ass Than a Dead Lion'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

What does this phrase signify 'Better a Live Ass Than a Dead Lion'? What is the moral of this phrase? What does the writer want to convey through this statement? Please explain and also make a sentence on it for better understanding.

I read this statement [here at 'Art Practical'](https://www.artpractical.com/review/better_a_live_ass_than_a_dead_lion/#:%7E:text=In%20presenting%20nature%20through%20a,what%20compels%20us%20to%20explore).

Comment: **discretion is the better part of valour** - [*it's better to avoid a dangerous situation than to confront it*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/discretion+is+the+better+part+of+valor#:~:text=proverb%20Caution%20is%20more%20important,when%20they%20are%20actually%20needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other animals are used in this proverb. I came across *A living ***donkey, rat*** or **dog***. About the variant with "a living dog" [OEDcom](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/56405) says:

> ***a living*** (also *live*) ***dog is better than a dead lion*** and variants: ‘where there's life, there's hope’, often used to assert the
> virtue of thoughtfulness or pragmatism, especially over heedlessness
> or heroism. With allusion to Ecclesiastes 9:4.

In case you wonder what the [Ecclesiastes 9:4](https://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/9-4.htm) says, here it is:

> For to him that is joined to all the living there is hope: for ***a living dog is better than a dead lion***.

I also found some synonym proverbs in this [dictionary of proverbs](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=86yPOGG3YfcC&pg=PT284&lpg=PT284&dq=proverb%20%22Better%20a%20Live%20Ass%20Than%20a%20Dead%20Lion%22&source=bl&ots=6whLG5IBts&sig=ACfU3U0GXQfrPIbcNHQuuKUqo0n5kI6m0g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLu4Kb7pHxAhU7DGMBHVbkAYoQ6AEwA3oECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=proverb%20%22Better%20a%20Live%20Ass%20Than%20a%20Dead%20Lion%22&f=false):

> - a live dog is better than a dead lion
> - a live trout is better than a dead whale
> - a living dog is better than a dead lion
> - better a live  ass than a dead lion
> - better a live beggar then a dead king
> - better a living beggar then a dead emperor
> - better be poor and live than rich and perish